# Datatables - Having data from two arrays display

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have two arrays that I am attempting to display in a table using Datatables.

I am successfully able to display one of the arrays just the way I am intending to do. When trying to include another array to display data from I am running into errors.

For example here is a code snippet of the successful showing of 1 array:

```js
const data = [{
    title: "Walk in",
    totalRevenue: 2002,
    growth: 3.2
  }, {
    title: "Retail",
    totalRevenue: 1231,
    growth: 2.2
  },
  {
    title: "Hospital",
    totalRevenue: 5421,
    growth: 1.9
  },
  {
    title: "Online",
    totalRevenue: 2442,
    growth: 3.2
  },
  {
    title: "Fitness",
    totalRevenue: 8742,
    growth: 0.3
  }
]

const otherData = [{
  newTitle: 'More data',
  newTotalRevenue: 2000,
  newGrowthRate: 3.2
}]

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    if (data[2] < 3) {
      $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  },
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [1, 2],
    "className": 'dt-body-right'
  }, ],
  data: data,
  responsive: true,
  paging: true,
  searching: false,
  bInfo: true,
  "order": [
    [2, "desc"]
  ],
  "pageLength": 20,
  columns: [{
      data: "title",
      title: "Title",
    },
    {
      data: "totalRevenue",
      title: 'Revenue'
    },
    {
      data: "growth",
      title: 'Revenue Growth'
    }

  ]
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: blue;
}

.backgroud-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.background-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

My array `data` is being displayed by having `data: data` in my datatable configuration. I've attempted to include a second array such called `otherData` and include it in my datatable such as : `data: [data, otherData]` but when doing so I am unable to display any data from either arrays.

Is there a way to display more then one array of data in datatables?

Here is a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuj593d0/6/):

Comment: It is possible. But since the `keys` are different in the otherData array. Hence why it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several problems in your fiddle.

- You're adding a 4th column that isn't available inside your data
- The keys inside your second array needs to match `columns.data` inside your Datatables init
- The way you're giving Datatables the set of data using an array of objects isn't how it's done and is a datatables syntax error

That being said, here's a working version :

```js
const data = [{
    title: "Walk in",
    totalRevenue: 2002,
    growth: 3.2
  }, {
    title: "Retail",
    totalRevenue: 1231,
    growth: 2.2
  },
  {
    title: "Hospital",
    totalRevenue: 5421,
    growth: 1.9
  },
  {
    title: "Online",
    totalRevenue: 2442,
    growth: 3.2
  },
  {
    title: "Fitness",
    totalRevenue: 8742,
    growth: 0.3
  }
]

const otherData = [{
  title: 'More data',
  totalRevenue: 2000,
  growth: 3.2
}]

var dataSet = data.push(...otherData)

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    if (data[2] < 3) {
      $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  },
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [1, 2],
    "className": 'dt-body-right'
  }, ],
  data: data,
  responsive: true,
  paging: true,
  searching: false,
  bInfo: true,
  "order": [
    [2, "desc"]
  ],
  "pageLength": 20,
  columns: [{
      data: "title",
      title: "Title",
    },
    {
      data: "totalRevenue",
      title: 'Revenue'
    },
    {
      data: "growth",
      title: 'Revenue Growth'
    }

  ]
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: blue;
}

.backgroud-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.background-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```